# UK postcode using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to know if there is a way to split correctly UK postcodes using XSLT 1.0.

For example:

```
PE92BD --> PE9 2BD
NE611PE --> NE61 1PE 
CV364AB --> CV36 4AB
SN13EG --> SN1 3EG
IP242AN --> IP24 2AN
```

Comment: What are the rules? Does the second part always consist of the last three characters?

Comment: yes the second part is always 3 characters as the sector of UK postcode is 0-9

Comment: @kokos Is your question not answered then?

Comment: No is not answered

Comment: @kokos Why not? What's missing?

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know if there is a way to split correctly UK postcodes
>   using XSLT 1.0.

Assuming that by "split correctly" you mean place a space before the last three characters, you can do:

```
<xsl:variable name="length" select="string-length($postcode)" />    
<xsl:value-of select="substring($postcode, 1, $length - 3)"/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($postcode, $length - 2)"/>
```

Comment: This works only when the post codes don't have a space in them. There needs to be some check first whether or not the post code has a space: not(contains($postcode,' ')) then implement the above function.

Comment: @Itsallgonepearshaped If your post codes can have spaces, you can start by translating them out - no need to check for anything.